# ios 8 hide navigationcontroller on scroll and show it again when scrolling a little bit up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to let the navigation controller disappear on scrolling in my tableview but when I stop I pull up a littlebit the navigationcontroller needs to be visible again. It's the effect as the facebook app with there searchbar in.

We are going to support iOS 8 only so I added this in my tableview viewdidload:

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
```

This hides the navigationbar on scroll but it hides it completely until the user scrolls all the way to the top.

Is there a way to achieve this effect in combination with this line or do I need to do it another way?

Comment: Following article explains the navigation bar interaction that iOS 8 supports. http://natashatherobot.com/navigation-bar-interactions-ios8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a very good library that does everything.

https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar

Comment: Just edit the answer instead of downvoting like that :(

Comment: ihatetoregister you downvote for the link make up? Really? This makes the library look bad.. Just edit the answer instead.

Comment: On the other hand you'll probably Never do it wrong again :) but it doesnt make the. Answer less correct.

Answer (score 2):

It should be sufficient with the one line you suggested

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
```

Just make sure you generate a downward swipe gesture, which could be hard to get right in the simulator. Just do a quick flick down and the navigation bar should be shown again. It might be easier to try it on a real device.

Comment: its working much simple, i am having a extension view below the navigation bar, while swiping up that view should fit at top and while swiping down it should fit below the navigation bar, anyother simple solution is there for this @ihatetoregister